# api authentication failing as trying with hash

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to match the api signatures with the following as:

```
API-Sign = Message signature using HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key
```

my code as of now

```
<cfset x = createobject("java","java.lang.System").currentTimeMillis()>
<cfset sts =  "https://api.exmaple.com/records" & hash(x, "SHA-512", "UTF-8")>
<cfset sig = tobase64(hmac(sts, "#secret_key#", "HMACSHA256"))>
```

but something is wrong, unable to validate, getting internal error

Comment: I don't see any POST data in your `hash()` call. Without more information from the API documentation it's hard to tell what the server expects. Are there no examples in the docs?

Comment: hmm, i will go and check, but it seems i am doing it wrong, i am doubling the hmac no?, can you guide me correctly in that piece